# Discord.py|Replacing channel with id

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

how do I specify the voice channel id instead of having the user enter it manually?

Discord.py

```
@bot.command()

async def online(ctx, channel: discord.VoiceChannel):  
    #replace channel:discord.VoiceChannel on voice channel id
    await channel.edit(name='Online:'+getonline())
```

Comment: Do you want to infer the correct channel from some property of the context, hardcode a value, or get it from the user in some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
```

When member change status eg. from offline to another status. Read the documentation for more details.